# How can I send an array from Javascript to Laravel server?

Tags: javascript, laravel

Am trying to get the number of student that are present or absent from a table and sending it to laravel server, by using jquery (each) to iterate through each table data and pushing each of the records to an array. Am new to programming. Thanks

This is my Javascript:

```
$('#submitRollCall').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let data = [];

    $('input').parents('tr').each(function(){

        const rollCallObj = {};

        rollCallObj.stdId = $(this).find('#stdId').val();
        rollCallObj.rollCall = $(this).find("input:checked").val();

        data.push(rollCallObj);
    })
    console.log(data)
    $.ajax({

        type:'POST',
        url: '/rollCall',
        beforeSend: function (xhr, type) {
            if(!type.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
            }
        },
        data:{
            'data': JSON.stringify(data)
        },
        success:function(data){
            if(data) {
                M.toast({html:'Roll-Call Successfully taken!'});
            } else {
                M.toast({html:'Not Success'});
            }
            console.log(data);
        },error:function(xhr, status, error){
            M.toast({html:"Pls Make sure to check each student"});
        }

    })
});
```

And my controller :

```
class RollCallController extends Controller
{
    public function rollCallSave(Request $request)
    {                
            $data = json_decode($request->input('data')) ;

            $rollCall = new RollCall();

            $rollCall->stdId = $data->stdId;

            $rollCall->rollCall = $data->rollCall;

            $rollCall->save((array)$data);

            return response()->json(['data' => $data]);

    }

}
```

I've 'dd($data)', it gives me the below :

```
array:10 [
  0 => {#206
    +"stdId": "10"
    +"rollCall": "1"
  }
  1 => {#201
    +"stdId": "9"
    +"rollCall": "1"
  }
  2 => {#202
    +"stdId": "8"
    +"rollCall": "1"
  }
  3 => {#208
    +"stdId": "7"
    +"rollCall": "1"
  }
  4 => {#209
    +"stdId": "6"
    +"rollCall": "1"
  }
]
```

This is the error I get while trying to submit:

```
{message: "Trying to get property 'stdId' of non-object", exception: "ErrorException",…}
exception: "ErrorException"
file: "C:\laravel\school\app\Http\Controllers\RollCallController.php"
line: 20
messag
```

e: "Trying to get property 'stdId' of non-object"

Comment: Logically your code seems fine, what is the issue that you are facing here ?

Comment: Because `json_decode` returns an array, you use object notation after. You can use array syntax : `$rollCall->stdId = $data['stdId'];`

Comment: I tried using this $rollCall->stdId = $data['stdId']; it returns undefined index 'stdId'. @Vincent Decaux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the dump of $data, you need to use a loop :

```
public function rollCallSave(Request $request)
{                
        $data = json_decode($request->input('data')) ;

        foreach ($data as $row) {
           $rollCall = new RollCall();
           $rollCall->stdId = $row->stdId;
           $rollCall->rollCall = $row->rollCall;
           // you don't need to pass $data here
           $rollCall->save();
        }

        return response()->json(['data' => $data]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Vincent Decaux. This works. But why didn't I have to pass in the '(array)$data' ?, If I may ask

Comment: Because you define the properties of your Model before. `save()` just save the model defined before, it doens't expect any parameter. You can use `RollCall::insert($row);` if you want too.